# iframe not appearing in smaller screens

Tags: html, jquery, css, iframe

I have an iframe that I want to appear upon clicking a button. Everything other than the iframe becomes blurry, and the iframe should appear horizontally centered on the screen. While the iframe is responsive for when I resize the screen, it is not properly appearing in smaller screens even after resizing them.

HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Affordable Excellence education">

    <title>Academic Forms - RHU</title>
    <!-- stylesheet -->
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">




    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">



    <style type="text/css">
        img.wp-smiley,
        img.emoji {
            display: inline !important;
            border: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
            height: 1em !important;
            width: 1em !important;
            margin: 0 0.07em !important;
            vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
            background: none !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>


    <link rel="stylesheet" id="contact-form-7-css" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">

    <link rel="stylesheet" id="main_css-css" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">


    <style media="screen">



    </style>


    <style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">
        h3 {
            font-size: 28.73px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            color: #3e76b4;
            font-family: 'Georgia', serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            display: block;
        }

        .main-header .search-bx .go-btn {
            background-color: #1a477b;
        }

        .main-header .search-bx .go-btn:hover {
            background-color: #0b376a;
        }

        .giving-btn {
            background-color: #ec7946;
            border: 1px solid #ec7946;
        }

        .giving-btn:hover {
            background-color: #dd6733;
            color: #fff;
            border-color: #dd6733;
        }

        .aef-form label {
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .aef-form .form-group-in {
            max-width: 300px;
        }

        .or-form .all {
            max-width: 300px;
        }

        div.wpcf7 .ajax-loader {
            display: block;
        }

        .wpb-js-composer .vc_tta.vc_general .vc_tta-panel-title {
            float: inherit;
        }

        .calendar-events-carousel .item h3 {
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .tuition-fees td {
            border: solid 1px #EBEBEB;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .about-wrap .contact-admission h2 {
            margin-top: 0px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .col-sm-8 ul li {
            padding-left: 20px;
            font-size: 16.76px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .col-sm-8 ol li {
            padding-left: 20px;
            font-size: 16.76px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }

        table tr:first-child td {
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function resizeIframe(obj) {
            obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body id="bodyFiles">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbarOverride">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="RHU" class="overrideLogo"></a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler overrideToggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link overrideNavItem" href="homepage.html">Home <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle overrideNavItem" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Academics
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="gpa.html">GPA</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="studyplan.html">Study Plan</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="courseregistration.html">Course Registration</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link overrideNavItem" href="#">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link overrideNavItem" href="files.html">Files</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link overrideNavItem" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link overrideNavItem" href="index.html" id="navLogout">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="filesMainContainer">
        <article>
            <div class="about-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="about-row academic-row academic-row2 mustafasArticle"
                            style="padding:20px 10px; border-top: 2px solid #734b6d; border-radius: 7px;  width: 100%; background-color: white; margin-top:20px;">
                            <h3 name="application-forms">Financial Forms</h3>
                            <div class="table-wrap">
                                <div class="table-body">
                                    <div class="table-row resources-row">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <h4><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                                                    <span>Statement of Fees
                                                        <sup>PDF</sup></span>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                <a href="#" class="download" style="color: #734b6d"
                                                    onclick="displayPDF(this)">Download</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row resources-row">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <h4><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                                                    <span>Tuition Fees
                                                        <sup>PDF</sup></span>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                <a href="#" class="download" style="color: #734b6d"
                                                    onclick="displayPDF(this)">Download</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row resources-row">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <h4><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                                                    <span>Financial Aid Application
                                                        <sup>PDF</sup></span>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" class="download"
                                                    style="color: #734b6d">Download</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--table-body ends-->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="about-row academic-row academic-row2 mustafasArticle"
                            style="padding:20px 10px; border-top: 2px solid #734b6d; border-radius: 7px;  width: 100%; background-color: white; margin-top:20px;">
                            <h3 name="application-forms">Application Forms</h3>
                            <div class="table-wrap">
                                <div class="table-body">
                                    <div class="table-row resources-row">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <h4><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                                                    <span>Request for Reactivation of Accepted
                                                        Application for Admission
                                                        <sup>PDF</sup></span>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" class="download"
                                                    style="color: #734b6d">Download</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row resources-row">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <h4><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                                                    <span>Request For Readmission Form
                                                        <sup>PDF</sup></span>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" class="download"
                                                    style="color: #734b6d">Download</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row resources-row">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                                <h4><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                                                    <span>Request for Reactivation of Enrollment
                                                        after
                                                        Leave of Absence
                                                        <sup>PDF</sup></span>
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" class="download"
                                                    style="color: #734b6d">Download</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--table-body ends-->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>
        </article>
    </div>


    <div id="filesPDF" class="hidden">
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>Rafik Hariri University &copy2023 All rights reserved </p>
        <div id="footerSocials">
            <p>Follow Us On</p>
            <div>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/school/rafik-hariri-university/" target="_blank"><img
                        src="images/linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin"></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rhu.lebanon/" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.png"
                        alt="Instagram"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>



    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
/*Files*/

#bodyFiles {
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}

#filesMainContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#filesMainContainer article {
    width: 95% !important;
    min-width: 95% !important;
}

#filesMainContainer .container {
    min-width: 95% !important;
    width: 95% !important;
}

#bodyFiles h3 {
    color: #734b6d !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#bodyFiles h4 {
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#bodyFiles h4:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247) !important;
}

#bodyFiles footer p {
    width: fit-content;
}

#bodyFiles footer {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

/* #bodyFiles #filesPDF h1{
    border:1px solid red;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
} */

.fileBodyHidden {
    filter: blur(3px);
}

#filesPDF {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height:700px;
    width:85%;
}

.PDF {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media(max-width:600px){
    #filesPDF{
        height:400px;
    }
}
```

**JS code**

```
function displayPDF(el) {
  $("body>*:not(#filesPDF)").addClass("fileBodyHidden");
  $("#filesPDF").removeClass("hidden");
  $("#filesPDF").append("<iframe class='PDF' src='pdf files/tuition.pdf' frameborder='0'></iframe>");
}
```

Comment: I ran your code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/yLRyWpW?editors=0010) with `src='https://picsum.photos/images'` in your JS code (instead of the *pdf*) and the `<iframe>` seems to respond just fine on smaller sizes. Something else must be out of the ordinary, maybe the PDF viewer lacks proper responsiveness.